# JQuery - What can I do to make this work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/piezack/X8D4M/5/

I need the change created by clicking the button to be detected. At the moment you have to click inside the field and then outside for it to detect any change.

Thanks guys.

The code for the button CANNOT be altered. Good tries so far though.

Was overcomplicating things. Answer http://jsfiddle.net/piezack/X8D4M/56/

Comment: what do you mean by 'The code for the button'?

Comment: If anyone is interested this was what I was looking for. Overcomplicated things. http://jsfiddle.net/piezack/X8D4M/55/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/X8D4M/11/) using [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
//waits till the document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('button.butter').click(function() {
        var $form6  = $('#FormCustomObject6Name');
        $form6.val('Text has changed');
        $form6.trigger('change')
    });

    $('#FormCustomObject6Name').change(function() {
        var x = $('#FormCustomObject6Id').val();

        $("a").filter(function() {
            return this.href = 'http://www.msn.com'
        }).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + x);
        alert(x);
    });

});
```

Comment: Wait it doesnt work. I cannot edit the the button in my system as it is an auto-generated thingy. :( so close too.

Comment: does that really solve the prob? ..thought it was that the click wasnt triggerd after the change?

Comment: i'm slightly confused as to what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

i think that jmar has the right idea...if i understand correctly you want to be able to type whatever in the box and without clicking out of it to have the button change it to the text has changed.

i dont know if that alert is really necessary, but you can do this if the alert is not needed:

http://jsfiddle.net/X8D4M/24/

Comment: I removed my answer because I misunderstood the question.  I believe his problem is that he's not getting a change event when the text field is updated programmatically (when the button is clicked), which mine didn't address.  Right now I'm just not sure why IAbstractDownVoteFactory's answer isn't sufficient...

Comment: If I understand his question correctly, then no, but I'm not sure that I actually understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the change event simply add a .trigger after setting the value.

Also, you're selector for the link wasn't working so I just changed it to #link.

http://jsfiddle.net/X8D4M/22/